# on jQuery change... using .html();

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK let's say I have a jQuery function... it's an AJAX Post... well after success I do this

```
$("#title"+id).html(Z);
```

and Z is `var Z=$("#"+X+" textarea.editAnswer").val();`.

However if I type in the textarea something like `<script>alert('Test');</script>` and then press save... it will save it and the test alert will popup. So... how do I fix this?

Comment: What is not desired? That alert popup happened or what?

Comment: Fix what? You didn't specify how the behaviour differs from what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **code injection** and should be avoided with HTML encoding.

Either:

1. return HTML encoded result from the server (after you've saved it) and populate that into your `#title` element or
2. use `escape()` Javascript function to encode it on the client and populate that result into your `#title` element

Depending on the scenario, you should always use the one that makes it harder for the user to hack. I'd suggest you use server side approach, because users won't be able to override your custom javascript function and address their own twisted agenda...

Comment: Yep. Right to the point. If someone typed in `</div>` your app would break as well, you need to encode it.

Comment: Then I get Yay%2C%20herp%21%3F%20%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27Test%27%29%3B%3C/script%3E in textarea. What the heck.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are escaping the code or using whitelists.

Do you need the html code? Take a look at this question: [How to prevent Javascript injection attacks within user-generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942011/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-within-user-generated-html)

And then these ones:

[Script injection - form validation (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657470/script-injection-form-validation-jquery)

[Do you only run htmlspecialchars() on output or is there other functionality you also do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526438/do-you-only-run-htmlspecialchars-on-output-or-is-there-other-functionality-you/527092#527092)